# Novel about a man who was taken by aliens and used as an ambassador because humans used to be the galactic diplomats aeons ago

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading a book ages ago (25-30 years or more) about a man who was taken by aliens and used as an ambassador because humans used to be the galactic diplomats aeons ago. At one point, he tells them to "get real," which is said to an alien who is extremely literal.

I cannot recall author or title. I'd really like to revisit this one if anyone has any idea.

In the book humans had an earlier civilization and returned to Earth to start a technological society.

Comment: "Get real!" has significance (like they become corporeal or something) or it is just a line you remember it having?

Comment: Just a line from the book, but it does have significance because it is said to an alien who is extremely literal.

Comment: worth editing question then to add this.